# How to stop Javascript interval function from restarting?

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I can't seem to figure out why my countdownclock function keeps restarting after reaching 00:00. It gets to 00:00 but then restarts from whatever I put in the prompt. I believe I need to add a condition such as a while #time != "00:00" but I'm not entirely sure how.

```js
function startTimer(duration, display) {
  var start = Date.now(),
    diff,
    minutes,
    seconds;

  function timer() {
    // get the number of seconds that have elapsed since 
    // startTimer() was called
    diff = duration - (((Date.now() - start) / 1000) | 0);

    // does the same job as parseInt truncates the float
    minutes = (diff / 60) | 0;
    seconds = (diff % 60) | 0;

    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

    if (diff <= 0) {
      // add one second so that the count down starts at the full duration
      // example 05:00 not 04:59
      start = Date.now() + 1000;
    }
  };

  // we don't want to wait a full second before the timer starts
  timer();
  setInterval(timer, 1000);
}

window.onload = function() {
  var choice = prompt("Minutes to launch")
  var setTheClock = 60 * choice,
    display = document.querySelector('#time');
  startTimer(setTheClock, display);
};
```

```html
<body style="width: 100vw; padding: 0; border: 0; margin: 0;">
  <div style="width: 60vh; padding: 0; border: 0; margin: 0 auto;">
    <p id="time" style="font-family:futura; font-size: 20vh; text-align: center; padding: 0; border: 0; margin-top: 40vh"></p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to clear the interval. Set the interval to a variable and clear it when it's finished otherwise, it will keep on going.

```js
function startTimer(duration, display) {
  var start = Date.now(),
    diff,
    minutes,
    seconds;

  function timer() {
    var interval;
    // get the number of seconds that have elapsed since 
    // startTimer() was called
    diff = duration - (((Date.now() - start) / 1000) | 0);

    // does the same job as parseInt truncates the float
    minutes = (diff / 60) | 0;
    seconds = (diff % 60) | 0;

    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

    if (diff <= 0) {
      // add one second so that the count down starts at the full duration
      // example 05:00 not 04:59
      start = Date.now() + 1000;
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  };

  // we don't want to wait a full second before the timer starts
  timer();
  interval = setInterval(timer, 1000);
}

window.onload = function() {
  var choice = prompt("Minutes to launch")
  var setTheClock = 60 * choice,
    display = document.querySelector('#time');
  startTimer(setTheClock, display);
};
```

```html
<body style="width: 100vw; padding: 0; border: 0; margin: 0;">
  <div style="width: 60vh; padding: 0; border: 0; margin: 0 auto;">
    <p id="time" style="font-family:futura; font-size: 20vh; text-align: center; padding: 0; border: 0; margin-top: 40vh"></p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Need to declare { interval }

Comment: TBH @codenoir , I don't have much experience with Intervals. It seems to be working, but I would think that I would need to declare it. But how?

Comment: Just the variable declaration for interval.  Somewhere up top, "var interval;".  That's all.

Comment: Okay @codenoir! I'm wondering why this is. Is it because I clear the Interval before I declare it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the `interval` in a variable and clear it when total time gets to 0.

Working solution.

```js
function startTimer(duration, display) {
  var start = Date.now(),
    diff,
    minutes,
    seconds,
    countDownTimer;

  function timer() {
    // get the number of seconds that have elapsed since 
    // startTimer() was called
    diff = duration - (((Date.now() - start) / 1000) | 0);

    // does the same job as parseInt truncates the float
    minutes = (diff / 60) | 0;
    seconds = (diff % 60) | 0;

    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

    if (diff <= 0) {
      // add one second so that the count down starts at the full duration
      // example 05:00 not 04:59
      start = Date.now() + 1000;
   clearInterval(countDownTimer); 
    }
  }

  // we don't want to wait a full second before the timer starts
  timer();
  countDownTimer = setInterval(timer, 1000);
}

window.onload = function() {
  var choice = prompt("Minutes to launch")
  var setTheClock = 60 * choice,
    display = document.querySelector('#time');
  startTimer(setTheClock, display);
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body style="width: 100vw; padding: 0; border: 0; margin: 0;">
  <div style="width: 60vh; padding: 0; border: 0; margin: 0 auto;">
    <p id="time" style="font-family:futura; font-size: 20vh; text-align: center; padding: 0; border: 0; margin-top: 40vh"></p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```